# Selenium how to find and click Business Manager option on Facebook Logout Menu

Tags: c#, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I'm trying to find and click a Business Manager option in the logout menu on Facebook.
Where is it? Log in to Facebook > Click the downward carrot icon on the top right of the screen (Next to the help icon) > Under business manager click "Mybusinessname"
(Keep in mind the `id=` is never the same)

Here is the HTML from right clicking the business name and inspecting:

```
<div class="clearfix _42ef"><span class="_51lp hidden_elem mts _5ugf _5ugh 
rfloat _ohf" id="u_8_6">0</span><div class="navSubmenuName 
ellipsis">MyBusinessName</div></div>
```

Ive tried finding it by partial link text and link text:

```
private By businessManagerOption = By.PartialLinkText("MyBusinessName");
```

Xpath:

```
/html/body/div[22]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[5]/a/span/span/div/div/div
```

CSS SELECTOR:

```
li._54ni:nth-child(5) > a:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2)
```

I have even tried changing `.click` to `.submit` and no luck.

```
public TimeLine chooseBusinessManager()
    {
        waitForElement(businessManagerOption).Click();
        return this;

    }
```

Comment: Scrapping [_Facebook_](https://www.facebook.com/) is against the [_ToS_](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms) and you are liable to be questioned and may even land up in [_Facebook Jail_](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=804287426255468). Use _Facebook API_ instead.

Comment: Your answer is no help. Go read facebook's robot.txt

Comment: Well, you're, of course, welcome to ignore the wishes of others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using the below xpath
`//div[contains(text(),'MyBusinessName')]`
Or

```
//div[@class='navSubmenuNameellipsis']//div[contains(text(),'MyBusinessName')]
```